# PHP Login form doesn't redirect to another page

Tags: php, authentication

validation process works well but it won't redirect to the new "profile.php " page. Pls let me know where I am going wrong.

Here is the html form.

```
<form name = "fomu_kuingia" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method = "POST">

        <br><br> Barua pepe: <input type="text" name="baruapepe"  />
          <span class = "error" style = "color: #DC143C;"> <?php echo $tatizo;  ?></span>  

        <br><br> Neno la siri:  <input type="password" name="nenosiri" />
         <span class = "error" style = "color: #DC143C;"> <?php echo $tatizo1;  ?></span>

         <br><br><input type="button" value="Nimesahau" name="nimesahau" /><input type="submit" value="Ingia " name="ingia "  />
          <span class = "error" style = "color: #DC143C;"> <?php //echo $jinaErr; ?></span>


        </form>
```

here is the php function to take data (email/ passed)

```
 <?php
           //$pepe = " ";
          // $siri = " ";



           function take_data()
        {    $pepe = "";
             $siri = "";

           if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
           {
               if (empty ($_POST["baruapepe"])||empty ($_POST["nenosiri"]))
                {  echo "<font color = '#DC143C' > TATIZO: Tafadhali ingiza barua pepe au neno siri </font>" ;  }


                else {  $pepe = verify($_POST["baruapepe"]);
                        $siri = verify($_POST["nenosiri"]);

                        kuingia ($pepe, $siri); }
           }
         }

           ?>
```

here if the function to verify data ;php function;

```
 <?php
           //$pepe = " ";
          // $siri = " ";

           function verify ($data)
           {
               $data = trim ($data);
               $data = stripslashes($data);
               $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
               return $data;
           }


           ?>
```

and fınally ıs the functıon to check logın (email,paswd) detaıls and redırect to new page .

```
<?php
           //$pepe = " ";
          // $siri = " ";


           function kuingia ($pp, $sr)
           {
               $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root');

               if (!$con)
               { echo "Connection was not possible ";}

               else 
               {
                   mysql_select_db('DalaliOnline', mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'));
                   $result = mysql_query("select jina1, jina2 from watumiaji where barua_pepe = '$pp' and neno_siri = '$sr' ");

                   if (!$result)
                   {    echo "Tatizo la mysql"; }

                   else if  (mysql_num_rows($result)== 0)
                   {    echo "<font color = '#DC143C' > TATIZO: Barua pepe au neno siri vimekosewa </font>" ;   }

                   else 
                   { header ("Location:profile.php");
                       echo "umefanikiwa kuingia"; }
               }
           }



           ?>
```

Comment: is there any output? have you got display_errors on?

Comment: after header() add exit() and not echo "";.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_*`. It's deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should read on [how to prevent them in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114).

Comment: @mithunsatheesh no errors outpetd

Answer (score 0):

Your `header()` call is sending a relative path for the `Location` header.

According to [the PHP documentation for `header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), the HTTP/1.1 spec requires an absolute URL:

> HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself

It looks like you are also missing a space between the colon (`:`) and the content of the header.

Another common gotcha (although I'm not seeing it in your code above) is that you can't call `header()` if you've already sent any output to the browser.

Comment: That doesn't matter. It works for me if i redirect with `header("Location: test.php");`.

Comment: @S.Pols: As the quoted part above says, some browsers accept relative URIs. Perhaps you are using a different browser than OP.

Comment: True, missed that, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The header location should be an absolute url, and **there should be a space** between `Location:` and the url, ie;

```
header ("Location: http://yoursite.com/profile.php");
```

Also make sure there is nothing outputted to the browser before that header is sent.

Hope this helps.